# Como leer lineas especificas de un fichero de texto plano en visual basic script

Tags: vbscript

Tengo un fichero de texto plano que contiene una serie de datos seccionados por una cabecera, pongo un ejemplo:

```
###   CONSENT00801  Consent Values  CONSENTONE00801+ Z00801.3, CONSENTTWO+ Z00801.7 ###

CONSENTONE0080101 half hourly
CONSENTONE0080102 daily
CONSENTONE0080103 monthly

CONSENTTWO0080101 half hourly
CONSENTTWO0080102 daily
CONSENTTWO0080103 monthly

###   CONSENT00803  Consent Values  CONSENTONE00803+ Z00803.3, CONSENTTWO00803+ Z00803.8 ###

CONSENTONE0080301 half hourly
CONSENTONE0080302 daily
CONSENTONE0080303 monthly

CONSENTTWO0080301 half hourly
CONSENTTWO0080302 daily
CONSENTTWO0080303 monthly

###   DDIVISION00801    Division i.e. fuel type DIVISIONONE00801 + Z00801.1, DIVISIONTWO00801 + Z00801.5  ###

DIVISIONONE0080101 electricity
DIVISIONONE0080102 gas

DIVISIONTWO0080101 electricity
DIVISIONTWO0080102 gas
```

Como se puede observar, las cabeceras tienen patrones comunes, por ejemplo, siempre empiezan con tres almohadillas seguidas de tres espacios.

Mi objetivo es conseguir leer de un archivo de texto únicamente las lineas que están debajo de una de estas cabeceras, es decir, todas las lineas de una sección, por ejemplo, leer las entradas de la sección...

```
###   CONSENT00803  Consent Values  CONSENTONE00803+ Z00803.3, CONSENTTWO00803+ Z00803.8 ###
```

Que vienen siendo ...

```
CONSENTONE0080301 half hourly
CONSENTONE0080302 daily
CONSENTONE0080303 monthly

CONSENTTWO0080301 half hourly
CONSENTTWO0080302 daily
CONSENTTWO0080303 monthly
```

Se como reconocer la palabra clave de la cabecera usando las expresiones regulares, lo que no se es como indicar que lea todas las líneas desde la siguiente linea a esa cabecera hasta que encuentre la siguiente.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo a mi mismo:

Conseguí solucionar el problema con otro objeto regex que detectaba la siguiente palabra clave, de tal manera que, combinando un bucle con una condición que comprobaba si la linea actual capturada era igual a la palabra detectada por ese objeto regex, conseguía lo que necesitaba.